# How to pass a bunch of lists as parameters in a function

Tags: c#, list, function, parameters

I need to pass a bunch of lists as parameters in a function.
The way to pass a single list is as given below

```
functionA()
{
   List<string>ColmnA = new List<string>();
   myfunction(ColmnA);
}

void myfunction(List<string> list1)
{

}
```

Now i have to pass six list as parameters, is this the only way or is there a shorter way to do this

Comment: Pass a `List<List<string>>`? Also 6 parameters? what do they represent? Maybe it should be a class with 6 properties? and passing a list of that?

Comment: If you have 6 parameters I would probably just pass them in rather than trying to lump them together and then having to peel them apart later.  That said - I suspect whatever you are trying to do could be refactored in some way so that you wouldn't need 6 lists...

Comment: they are all string datatype, i am reading a csv file

Comment: ya but what do they represent?

Comment: they represent sample name and values

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `params` keyword:

```
void myfunction(params List<string>[] list1)
{    
}
```

So now you can call this function as:

```
myfunction(new List<string>(), new List<string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has a `params` feature.  You can utilize it like this

```
void MyFunction( params List<string>[] myStrings ) { }
```

and then calling it

```
MyFunction( new List<string>(), new List<string>(), ...etc );
```

or

```
MyFunction( new []{ new List<string>(), new List<string>() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you need to think how you are sending the information. Tipically you could think on creating an object that contains what you need and then send that objact as parameter. Example:

```
public class YourObject
{
    List<string> List1 { get; set; }
    List<string> List2 { get; set; }
    List<string> List3 { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your function...

```
void myfunction(YourObject bunchOfLists)
{
     //do something
}
```

Anyway, you have to think if this is your best approach depending on your model and business logic. Try to merge lists according with some kind of logic inside your needs. Don´t add the lists freely because it is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing all of the lists from `functionA()` then you can either pass them as individual parameters (i.e. `myfunction(List<string>list1, List<string>list2, List<string>list3, List<string>list4, List<string>list5, List<string>list6)`) or you can pass them as a single list of lists `myfunction(List<List<string>>stringLists)`